# How to prevent user from login if they put wrong input in

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, passwords

im not sure how to fix this error. I get a blank page when user login if they enter the wrong input. If they enter info that doesn't  exist in the database. Please help :)

login.php

```
<?php 
 include ("base.php");
 include ("passwordchecker.php");
 include ("functions.php");

    $error = "";

    function postInput($htmlName)
    {
        if(isset($_POST[$htmlName]))
        {
            return $_POST[$htmlName];
        }
        return null;
    }

    //check if the user is already login.
            if(isset($_SESSION['userid']))
            {
                //check the database for existing user.
                $usercheck = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = ?");
                $usercheck->bind_param("i",$_SESSION['userid']);
                $usercheck->execute();
                $usercheck->store_result();
                $results = $usercheck->num_rows;
                if($results == 1)
                {
                    redirect("languages.php");
                }
            }

    $loginusername = postInput('username');
    $loginpassword = postInput('password');



    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        if($loginusername == "" || $loginpassword == "")
        {
            $error = "Please Enter your user name and password";

        }
        else
        {
                //user isnt logged in
                if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userid, password FROM user WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param("s",$loginusername);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($userid,$correctHash);
                    $stmt->fetch();
                    if(ValidatePassword($loginpassword,$correctHash))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
                        redirect('languages.php');
                    }
                    die();
                    $stmt->close();
                }
                else
                {
                    $error = "You dont exist in Database."
                }
        }
    }



?>
```

passwordchecker.php

```
<?php
    function HashPassword($password)
    {
        $salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
        $hash = hash("sha256", $salt . $password);
        $final = $salt . $hash;
        return $final;
    }

    function ValidatePassword($password, $correcthash)
    {
        $salt = substr($correcthash, 0, 64);
        $validhash = substr($correcthash, 64, 64);

        $testhash = hash("sha256", $salt . $password);

        return $testhash == $validhash;
    }
?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
    function redirect($page)
    {
        header("Location: " . $page);
        exit();
    }
?>
```

base.php

```
 <?php
        session_start();

        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbname = "login";
        $dbuser = "root";
        $dbpass = "DirectedStudies2012";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
?>
```

Comment: Kudos for using a prepared statement though, instead of the endless onslaught of string-concatenation and mysql_* that we see here...

Comment: a username and password that dont exist in the database

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you have code after `die()` that will never be called since `die()` will stop the execution immediately.

Comment: Use a 303 redirect on form posts like this `header("Location: $page", TRUE, 303)`, not the default 302 redirect.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to add an else to the following conditional

```
            if(ValidatePassword($loginpassword,$correctHash))
            {
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
                redirect('languages.php');
            }
```

i.e

```
            if(ValidatePassword($loginpassword,$correctHash))
            {
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
                redirect('languages.php');
            } else {
                redirect('backtoyourloginscreen.php');
            }
```

PS: $error = "You dont exist in Database." is missing a semi colon ;)

Answer (score 0):

Quickly scanning your code it seems you keep track of an $error variable, but dont really output it. Try echo'ing it to send it to your client.

```
echo $error;
```

Comment: i did echo the error in the form code but it doesnt show up. If I add the else to the if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userid, password FROM user WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1")) I get a parse error for unexpected }

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `header("Location: ".your page)` instead of the `die()` statement.